# How to start a new activity from Textview/Button of a Fragment inside a Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, android-tablayout, android-tabactivity

[image: Tabbed Activity]

As showing in the above picture, I have created a Fragment named CustomerFragLogin with the code as follows :-

```
    public class customerFragLogin extends Fragment {
    

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public customerFragLogin() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static customerFragLogin newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        customerFragLogin fragment = new customerFragLogin();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_customer_login, container, false);
    }


}
```

Now, when I click on 'Login' button or 'Forget password' textview I want to open a new activity. How do I implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your CustomerFragLogin

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NotNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        
        TextView textView= findViewById(R.id.textView)
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class));   
            }
        });
       
    }
```

make sure your activity is declared in the manifest

Comment: Okay but findViewById() isn't working in Fragment so how do I get the id of that view ?

Comment: use the view object from parameter in the function to find view.

TextView textView= findViewById(R.id.textView)